# How to theme Commerce Customer profile?

Tags: theming, commerce, users

In a Commerce project, I added some custom fields to the customer profile, and I’m using [Addressbook](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook). The customer profile is now displayed in the *address book tab* of each user page.

I need to change the display of this address book. Until now :

- I changed basic display settings of the fields in the "Manage Display" form, and this had a surprising effect : setting a label as hidden removed completely the default theming of all the view.
- I tried to use `hook_field_formatter_info()` and `hook_field_formatter_view()` as per that [Clive answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34500/how-can-i-display-the-value-of-an-addressfield-in-a-single-line) : this is great but it alters only the native AddressFields, not the custom fields of the customer profile.
- In the *Commerce Addressbook Defaults  view*, source of the display, there's only one field in the view : *Commerce Customer Profile: Rendered Commerce Customer profile*.

[image]

I could call the fields one by one in the view, but what if I want to alter directly the  **Rendered Commerce Customer profile** field ? Where is it built, and how can I theme or alter it?

Comment: That Views field just renders an entity in a particular view mode. It's provided by entity.module (I think the actual code is [`entity_views_handler_field_entity::render_single_value()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21views%21handlers%21entity_views_handler_field_entity.inc/function/entity_views_handler_field_entity%3A%3Arender_single_value/7)). So I think _manage display_ should work as normal. Could you provide some screenshots of what goes wrong?

Comment: Tks Andy. indeed, manage display works fine, like reordering fields or hide/display labels... What I mentioned is while I used manage display, the default markup which was an awful <h3> for labels, disappeared, and now, remained only a few <span>. So I was wondering why, but I'm especially searching how I can change this render and put mine...

Comment: So you'd like to know how to theme field output if I understand correctly?

Comment: @Andy, I'd like to theme that "Rendered Commerce Customer profile", which appears as a field in that view, but contains the whole customer profile, address fields + custom fields plus edit/delete links ;-) I would be glad to learn that

Comment: Sorry I was a bit ambiguous - I didn't mean _Views_ field, just normal core fields. I'll post an answer describing the overall field render process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you can theme field output [like other Drupal output](https://www.drupal.org/node/341628). If you use devel_themer* you can normally see the template used and suggestions available. [By default fields use `theme('field')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.default.inc/function/field_default_view/7) which [by default has a number of suggestions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7):

```
// Add specific suggestions that can override the default implementation.
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array(
  'field__' . $element['#field_type'],
  'field__' . $element['#field_name'],
  'field__' . $element['#bundle'],
  'field__' . $element['#field_name'] . '__' . $element['#bundle'],
);
```

For example, the first suggestion allows you to override the template/function used for a particular type of field. In this case we could create `MYTHEME_field__addressfield()` and it would be used for addressfields only. [You can add your own suggestions as well](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440).

There are some field API routes as well though. You can use contrib or [custom formatters](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7) (some of which in turn provide their own theme functions that you can override). Formatters can have settings that might give the results you want. You can [add extra settings with a contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_settings) if you want to extend a formatter. There are also some field-specific hooks that might be useful:

- [`hook_field_attach_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7)
- [`hook_field_attach_preprocess_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_preprocess_alter/7)

* As you say devel_themer is heavy. It massively changes the markup, and often messes up your JS. I only ever switch it on when I need it and then switch if off immediately afterwards, YMMV!

Comment: well tks. I installed devel_themer (huge but heavy). Now I can see that the view is rendered by views-view-fields.tpl.php. pb is when I dsm into the view, there is stil the same lone field, or I have to deep far into, to get such variables : `dsm($view); $result = $view->result[0]; 
$entity = $result->_entity_properties[entity object];

$tel_value = $entity->field_user_tel['und'][0]['value'];` and so on... but it seems quite heavy just to theme the address book ? and I can't find some pieces like delete and edit links...

Comment: last, sorry I'm not sure I understand well the `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array()`...

Comment: I've updated the Q a bit regarding devel_themer and suggestions. devel_themer isn't perfect, but I was expecting you'd be able to select inside the Views field to the Drupal fields attached to the customer entity. (I'd expect it to show something like `theme_field()` or `field.tpl.php` if you've selected the Drupal field.)

Comment: Indeed, fields are themed by Fences .tpl & by `theme_addressfield_container()` ... I'll have to deep into the different solutions you purposed. Unfortunately at the moment I can't find specifically how the *Rendered Commerce Customer profile field* was rendered, but I also realised, blind I am, that each field is there in the view UI, so I can do the usual way... anyway I learned a lot today. Many thanks for your efforts to help & make this clear for my poor mind ;)